# Could not deploy functions on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

After running the command line `firebase deploy --only functions`, I have these errors:

[image]

**Below you may find also the logs in the firebase:**
[image]

**I tried multiple times to run the command for deploy and the logs show different messages, these the last ones:**

```
11:13:12.563 PM
api
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Function cannot be initialized.
 
11:13:12.615 PM
api
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs"},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"taobardhi@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/clone-react-dfee2/locations/us-central1/functions/api"}
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question so that it's easy to read and search.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to make changes or additions using the "edit" link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your error might be probably caused by a syntax code error or any other code problem.

As the error message recommends you will find further information about the error by examining the corresponding entry log in the Cloud Console:

`https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs`

Another option would be to run your [functions locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) before deploying them to check if they work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar error `"code": 3` on firebase console while deploying a cloud function.

For me, adding module dependencies in `package.json` file with correct version numbers and running `npm` install (with **`0 vulnerability`**) worked.